# Loop: add sequence number, delete columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know the VBA script for the Loop: Add sequence number (start number 1000 and 1001,1002,1003 so on) to the specific column and delete the another specific columns from multiple excel files into one folder. The purpose is to have the exact excel format to process the data in the special software.
I am beginner with VBA code.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowC As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Let us assume that values appear in Column C. Find last row of column C
        LastRowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        'Add Values in Column B
        For i = 1 To LastRowC
            .Range("B" & i).Value = i + 1000
        Next i

        'Clear Column A
        .Columns("A:A").Clear

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your attention, it gave me the run time error 9, could not run

Comment: This line? *.Columns("A:A").Clear*

Comment: after Alt+F11 and I copy-paste your VBA code, and error windows pop-up and it says error line '9', I did it in Spyder with Python code, but know I can not delete the last row of each excel file because of it contains some empty boxes, for example I need to delete the rows where C olumn has 0-zero value

Answer (score 0):

```
dim i as integer
i = 1000
dim max as integer
max = 1000000
while i < max
   begin
     set i = i + 1
     ' do funky column editing , deleting, whatever 
   end
```

Comment: with this VBA code it will add the number till the 1000000, if you have python code that can run on anaconda spyder can be ok for me, python 3x or 2x, thank you for your time